# Bulk Capacitors

Tags: capacitor, decoupling-capacitor, bulk-capacitor

I'm looking at a design that is using 2x220uf bulk capacitors (while other 2 are placeholders).

these capacitors are used in Validation Platform for some CPU. I was wondering if I can replace these large capacitors with multiple small capacitors that achieve the same capacitance. for example 47uf x 9 + 10uf x 2 = 443uf (instead of 220uf x 2 = 440 uf).

the reason is that I don't want to use 220uf capacitors like in the CRB since they are too large (7343).

Comment: You have to consider ESR and ripple current capability. ESR should be similar than the original design (not lower) and ripple current should be at least as high.

Comment: If the ESR is too low you can always add resistors in series with the replacement caps to make up for it. Also, ripple current will probably be somewhat to very dependent on the value of ESR.

Comment: Thanks for the information. to be honest, while looking at datasheets, I hardly could find information about ESR. maybe in just one kind of capacitors that is defined under LLR. I wonder if for small capacitors (0402, 0603) ESR is not relevant and that the reason vendors don't really relate to it.

Comment: There is DF (dissipation factor) for electrolytic capacitors. And for ceramic caps, highly frequency dependent ESR can be found in detailed datasheets on the manufacturer's website.